# Optimizing code about count prime numbers in an array and print the result simultaneously

Tags: c++

I'm making a program where the user will input the number of numbers he wants, and the output is the result of checking prime numbers or not simultaneously.

I know it's very simple, but I couldn't find a similar case study on the internet and finally decided to ask here as my last straw.

The thing is this code worked well for me, but it doesn't pass the time limit given. Is there any way to optimize this code?

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
  int x[100], rows, i, j, count = 0, cn = 0;
  
  scanf("%d", &rows);
  
  for(i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &x[i]);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    count = 0;
    int j = 1;
    while(j <= x[i]) {
      if(x[i] % j == 0)
      {
        count++;
      }
      j++;
    }
    if(count == 2) {
      printf("YES \n", x[i]);
      cn++;
    }
    else {
      printf("NO \n", x[i]);
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Implementing a more efficient algorithm (like a prime sieve) will yield orders of magnitude more performance than trying to optimize this naive algorithm.

Comment: ***Is there any way to optimize this code?*** Your algorithm is not efficient so the optimization will not solve the problem.

Comment: @drescherjm: Optimization includes changing algorithms. It does not just mean optimization by a compiler.

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks for the advice, I will research more on the topic!

Comment: I took it to mean asking to optimize this code. The optimization would be to throw it away and use a better / more efficient algorithm.

Comment: Aside from changing the algorithm there are some obvious things to fix: `x[i] % 1` is always going to be 0. Next test if `x[i] % 2 == 0`. And then start `j` at 3 and increment it by 2 each time. And change the loop to `while (j * j <= x[i])`. No number above `sqrt(x[i])` can be a factor other than `x[i]` itself, which, like 1, doesn't count. Last abort the loop once you find a factor. The number is not getting any less prime. Easiest to do if you make a function `bool isPrime(int)`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow thanks, it work wonders! And do you in case know how to use two different bool in a code? I'm trying to make a code to find a nearly prime number by using bool to find factors and another bool to check primeness of the factors but got stuck in the main driver. Is it possible to do this, though?

Comment: @ZA If you want prime factors then every time you find a factor divide your number by that factor as much as possible. So when you start with 12 you find 2 and 12 => 6 => 3. Then you find 3 and 3 => 1 and you are done. You can't find any non prime factors.